# Can apps on the playstore be downloaded by age group below the set target audience in google play console?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Im wondering if i set age group 13+ on my app, will it be visible to the age group below 13 on the playstore? Maybe with parent consent? Or can it not be downloaded at all if the account is below 13 years old?

Answer (score -2):

Parental controls don't prevent restricted content as a search result or through a direct link.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)